# How do I file an inheritance on my New Jersey tax return?

Tags: united-states, taxes, inheritance, turbotax, new-jersey

I inherited a bit of money from a grandparent that passed away last year.  New Jersey has an inheritance tax but from what I looked up close family inheritance is not taxable.  I want to make sure that I am doing my tax return correctly.  I'm trying to use Turbo Tax to file but I'm not sure how to input this.  I don't want to just add it as income because it wasn't normal income.

Comment: Wasn't it repealed? https://www.tiaa.org/public/offer/services/individual-advisory-services/repeal-of-the-nj-estate-tax Did TurboTax not ask anything from within the state forms?

Comment: I tried to find anything about inheritance in turbotax but couldn't.  If its repealed do I just not report the income at all?

Comment: I ma not a tax expert and know nothing about NJ, but inheritance/estate tax in my experience has a VERY high exemption level (it's only meant to tax vary large estates). So you may not need to declare anything. That said, you might also look at the instructions for the NJ forms and see if that sheds any light that TT might be missing.